# Aukus deal. Was Australia called in to share ballooning development costs?

Tags: military, australia, financing, aukus

The [Aukus deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUKUS) is a trilateral security pact between Australia, the Uk and the US. The biggest part of the pact is the acquisition of nuclear powered submarines [jointly developed by the three countries](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-64945819), although Australia will have a minor role.

The deal itself came as a surprise because initially Australia was not interested in nuclear powered submarines and to carry on the deal they had to [cancel a deal with France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUKUS#France) to acquire diesel-electric submarines.

The huge costs involved in the deal:

> Australia's PM said the plan - which will cost Canberra up to A$368bn (£201bn) over 30 years

and the doubts about the necessity of such weapons made me wonder whether Australia was called in to give financial support to a project whose cost were spiralling out of control. So. Do the financial reasons mattered a lot more than the military reasons to get in the project?

Note: A further detail about the project. I do not know whether this is the open issue. But it is enough to raise some doubts. The [submarines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSN-AUKUS) that Australia is expected to acquire should be powered by the [Rolls-Royce PWR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_PWR#PWR3) reactors. Those reactors are an evolution of an American [S9G reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S9G_reactor). According to Wikipedia:

> the MoD awarded Rolls-Royce a £600 million contract to produce reactors for the Dreadnought-class and also for the final boat of the Astute-class

It means £120 million per submarine (4+1) Not only it is an expensive project, it is behind schedule:

> the National Audit Office reported that the construction of the plant was five years behind schedule

Comment: Well, Australia will buy a few Virginia class that are already built in large numbers, so the answer on that side, is probably no. OTOH the new [SSN-AUKUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSN-AUKUS) will be tailor made for the UK and Australia, albeit with some US tech. So clearly Australia will pay for the development of the latter, but the decision to do that rather than buy more Virignias is probably more on the Australian side. With the opacity of high-level arms deal negotiations, I suspect we can't have more certainty than this.

Comment: @RickSmith Why removing the tag military-spending? I know it is new, but I think it is useful, the argument as this QA often strays from military necessity.

Comment: @Fizz Note that AUstralia will contribute to the development of the reactors for the propulsion and currently the US and the UK need to develop the new generation reactors which is missing.

Comment: I'm not privy to those details. Wikipedia says that the new class ""will have a high degree of commonality" with the Virginia class", so YMMV. Also, the new-class boats for Australia will be built in Australia, which is probably a large part of the negotiations.

Comment: Regarding the tag edit, the question is about financing the development of weapons and I should probably have used [tag:weapons], rather than [tag:military]. In any case, there are other questions regarding the costs of weapons. The problem is determining which of those questions should be retagged, and with what. This *should* begin with research identifying those similar questions and a question posted to Politics Meta. There appear to be about 20 questions with an assortment of tags concerning military and/or weapons spending, budgets, financing, etc., that may be retagged.

Answer (score 1):

### Almost Certainly Not

What leverage does the UK have over Australia that could cause them to act against their own self interest? - especially in terms of military readiness, where states tend to be at their most "selfish."

### Capabilities

Diesel Submarines and Nuclear Submarines are **very** different in terms of their capabilities. Diesel submarines are very quiet when they are on the battery, but they are slow to re-position and loud when dieseling to recharge or travel on the surface. Basically, diesel boats are very useful for coastal defense, but cannot project power abroad at all.

A Nuclear sub has the endurance, stealth, and speed to threaten ships or shore facilities far from home. This provides a viable counter to spreading Chinese influence in the Asia-Pacific that a diesel boat cannot.

### Win-Win-Win

The most likely answer is a win-win-win deal:

- The US saw a chance to gain a deterrent against China at the low cost of sharing nuclear tech with a close ally
- The UK saw a chance to lower the per-unit-cost of their new ship by sharing the design with the a close ally
- The Australians saw the opportunity to field a **far** more capable vessel without investing in a massively expensive indigenous nuclear program

It is possible that Australian thoughts on what "threat level" China presented changed between 2007, when the Collins class [replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack-class_submarine) process started, and 2021 when AUKUS was signed. The perception that China was more aggressive in the region would make a more credible threat more attractive to the Australians.

### Behind Schedule?

OP references a reactor as being behind schedule, but it's important to read the rest of the sentence in that [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_PWR#PWR3) entry:

> In January 2020, the National Audit Office reported that the construction of the plant was five years behind schedule and was now forecast to be in service in 2026.

So the Audit Report was nearly two years old when the AUKUS deal was signed. Working reactors in 2026 seems consistent with the [planned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSN-AUKUS) late 2020s (UK) and early 2030s (Australia) deployment dates for the ships.

Comment: "What leverage does the UK have over Australia ? " Then how come UK can prison an Australian citizen (Julian Assange), and not a peep from Australia ?

Comment: @Neel - I'm not sure how the extradition status of one accused criminal is relevant to a multi-billion dollar defense acquisition program

Comment: Wistleblowers are NOT criminals. The fact that you consider him a criminal, shows how much you are being influenced by US/UK propaganda.